# How to prevent jQuery flash from shifting text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After performing a process, a flash appears at the top of the screen with some basic information (ex. "Table Added"). When this happens, all the elements in the page get shifted down as the flash drops down from the top. The flash stays for a little bit, then disappears. The text, after the flash is gone, then shifts up to its original position.

How would I get the flash to not shift the elements on the page?

The code for the flash is in jQuery, which I am unfamiliar with. Here's the code:

```
function controller_jsSetError(type, msg) {

   $('#errorMessage').html(msg);
   if(type == 'NONE') {
      $('#errorMessage').hide();
   }
   else {
      $('#errorMessage').attr('class','ui-state-error ui-corner-all');
      $('#errorMessage').show();
   }
   if(type == 'STATUS') {
      $('#errorMessage').attr('class','ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all');
      $('#errorMessage').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
   }
}
```

Thanks you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more question of the CSS. Your code just shows and hides the flash message. What you need is to position these message boxes absolute.

See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sBXPh/)!

```
<div class="outerBox">
    <span id="errorMessage">ERROR!</span>
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>

<button onclick="$('#errorMessage').toggle();">show/hide error message</button>
```

CSS:

```
.outerBox {
    background:#eee;
    padding:20px;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}

#errorMessage {
    display:none;
    background:red;
    padding:30px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I added $('#errorMessage').css({position: 'absolute'}); and it works perfectly now. Also had to readjust the width, but that was no problem. Thank you again for a quick response!

Comment: I prefer to hide those flash messages by CSS and toggle them with jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

```
Try adding a preventDefault() at the beginning of your code- see below. 

function controller_jsSetError(type, msg) {
event.preventDefault();
$('#errorMessage').html(msg);
if(type == 'NONE') {
  $('#errorMessage').hide();
 }
else {
  $('#errorMessage').attr('class','ui-state-error ui-corner-all');
  $('#errorMessage').show();
 }
if(type == 'STATUS') {
  $('#errorMessage').attr('class','ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all');
  $('#errorMessage').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
  }
 }
```